# How to use segue in footer to pass label data to different sections?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, segue, pass-data

I have successfully been able to pass the label data of the ItemsVC to the Fees VC when pressing a button in the footer cell

but I can't seem to get it to work when trying to pass the label for the section in the tableview to the FeesVC

Im trying to pass the subtotal from the ItemsVC footer to the FeesViewController labels from different sections instead of it only passing the data of one section

I have successfully passed the data from the footer (when button is pressed). which successfully has been able to pass the totalPriceLbl from the BrandFooter to the Fees VC but can't pass the data from the right section to the FeesVC if that makes any sense how would I be able to pass the correct label data to the fees when the button is pressed

I feel like im really close to my solution im just off somewhere

and I think the problem is in the viewForFooterInSection that passes the subtotal(value) from the section to the FeesVC

thanks in advance for any help provided

```
class ItemsViewController: UIViewController {

    var brandItems: [BrandItem] = []
    var groupedBrandItems: [String: [BrandItem]] = [:]
    var brandSectionTitle: [String] = []

    var selectedLabel: String?             // Populates label data in FeesVC

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        groupedBrandItems = Dictionary(grouping: brandItems, by: {$0.products.brandName})
        brandSectionTitle = groupedBrandItems.map{$0.key}.sorted()
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        }if let vc = segue.destination as? FeesViewController {
            vc.stringPassed = selectedLabel!            // Populates label data in FeesVC
        }
    }
}

extension ItemsViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return brandSectionTitle.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let brand = brandSectionTitle[section]
        return groupedBrandItems[brand]!.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let brandCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BrandCell") as! BrandCell

        let brand = brandSectionTitle[indexPath.section]
        let brandItemsToDisplay = groupedBrandItems[brand]![indexPath.row]
        brandCell.configure(withCartItems: brandItemsToDisplay.products)

        return brandCell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let brandHeader = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BrandHeader") as! BrandHeader

        let headerTitle = brandSectionTitle[section]
        brandHeader.brandName.text = "Brand: \(headerTitle)"

        return brandHeader
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let brandFooter = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BrandFooter") as! BrandFooter

        let brand = brandSectionTitle[section]
        let arrAllItems = groupedCartItems[brand]!
        var subtotal: Float = 0
        for item in arrAllItems {
            if item.products.selectedOption == 1 {
                subtotal = subtotal + (Float(item.products.price) * Float(item.products.count))
            }

        let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        numberFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
        let total = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: Float(subtotal)))

        brandFooter.totalPrice.text = String(Total!)

        //trying to pass each section subtotal to FeesVC
        self.selectedLabel = "\(subtotal)"  // passes code to FeesVC

        return brandFooter
    }

}
```

---

```
class FeesViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var feesView: UIView!

    @IBOutlet weak var subtotalLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var salesTaxLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var totalLbl: UILabel!

    var stringPassed = String()     // Populates label data in FeesVC

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let tax = Float(stringPassed)! * Float(0.0825)
        let total = Float(stringPassed)! + tax

        let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        numberFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
        let subTotal = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: Float(stringPassed)!))
        let salesTax = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: Float(tax)))
        let overallTotal = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: Float(total)))

        subtotalLbl.text = subTotal
        salesTaxLbl.text = "(\(String(describing: salesTax!)))"
        totalLbl.text = "(\(String(describing: overallTotal!)))"
     }

    @IBAction func returnButton(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        print("Close Taxes and Fees")
    }    
}
```

---

***Update*** :

[image]

I keep getting the same subtotal and calculations in the FeesVC when im trying to post the subtotal for each section whenever the moreinfo button is pressed

`self.selectedLabel = "\(subtotal)"`

this line of code in viewForFooterInSection works successfully in passing the subtotal when the button is pressed for one section but it just doesn't pass the subtotal for every section when the button is pressed in their appropriate footer

Comment: So to clarify, the subtotal is only calculating from one cell's data and not getting the sum of all the cell's data?  Sorry, trying to understand

Comment: ***@drfalcoew*** Im getting the sum for all the cells in the section fine, its more showing the sum for each section in the FeesVC since im only getting the sum of one of the sections in the FeesVC ill post an image soon to show you what I mean.

Comment: Hi, check out my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**first** declare an array of doubles to store each one of your subtotals.

```
var subTotalArray[Double] = [Double]()
```

**Then**, when you are calculating your subtotals inside your viewForFooterInSection function, initialize your created array like so (change according to your code & variable names):

```
subTotalArray[section] = subtotal 
// use the local variable "section" to iterate
// and assign the subtotal to the correct section footer
```

**Next** to determine which info button was pressed in order to get the correct subtotal data, you can configure the tag property of the moreInfo button inside your viewForFooterInSection function.  Assign the tag like so:

```
moreInfo.tag = section
```

**Finally** with all these variables in place, we can correctly assign, determine, and gather each individual subtotal with a handler function connected to your moreInfo button.

```
func handleMoreInfo(sender: UIButton) { 
    selectedLabel = subTotalArray[sender.tag]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming what I understood from your problem you need to pass subtotals to other VC.

what you're doing wrong is saving the subtotal in one variable in footerForSection , this var will have the last subtotal of last footer section(this is what is happening in your code)

```
self.selectedLabel = "\(subtotal)"  // passes code to FeesVC
```

**EDIT**

So in your scenario you need to save subtotals in a array and when you tap a section footer , at the tap get the index of section and use the array to get the data and pass it on to other VC

Comment: how would I be able to create the Array to do that? since I'm a little confused at how to do that?

Comment: whenever you are calculating subtotal then at that time store them in a global array , you must have handled the tap right ? so at that time get the index of footer section and get the value from array at that particular index, if you still having issues let me know , I will edit my answer then

Comment: thank you that means a lot ❤️ I will work on this through the night and let you know about the results. I understand the approach that you're giving for this, it's just more of how I can figure out how to make it work lol

Comment: yes I have been trying still not succeeding at getting any adequate results, no matter what Ive tried it still doesn't work. How would I be to make this global array work because i really need the help to make this work. And thank you for checking up on me you're really kind for being here for me.

Comment: could you assist me in this, i am still having an issue trying t figure out your solution